# How do I compile assembly code so that I can see the hex byte code of it?

Tags: linux, assembly, x86

I have a simple assembly code file called exit.s that looks like the following:

```
.text
.globl _start
_start:
        xor %eax, %eax
        mov %al, 1
        xor %ebx, %ebx
```

I would like to get the hex byte code of this. How would I do this on a linux machine?  What commands would I use?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `gcc` to compile it into an executable, then use `objdump -d` to print out the code:

```
gcc -c -o my_file.o my_file.s
objdump -d my_file.o
```

Comment: When I try to compile it using gcc I get a bunch of errors such as `/tmp/ccLqYN5a.o: In function `_start':
(.text+0x0): multiple definition of `_start'
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/crt1.o(.debug_info): relocation 0 has invalid symbol index 11`

Comment: To only build an object file, not try to create a complete executable.

Answer (score 1):

The main thing here is you need a hex editor or viewer. There are plenty of free ones that you can find.

After you assemble the file, you will have an output file, which is often in ELF format, meaning that there is extra information in a header at the start of the file. You can tell `ld` to create a flat binary file with nothing but the assembly instructions by using the `oformat` flag:

```
$ld file.o -oformat binary
```

Then if you open up your resulting executable with a hex editor, you will see the machine code that the assembler generated.